# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code, showing the canvas:

```
 <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="550" height=600"></canvas>
 <canvas id="playerCanvas" width="550" height=600"></canvas
 <canvas id="enemiesCanvas" width="550" height=600"></canvas>
```

This is where the problem is said to occur:

```
game.contextBackground = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas").getContext("2d"); // line 32
game.contextPlayer = document.getElementById("playerCanvas").getContext("2d"); // line 33
game.contextEnemies = document.getElementById("enemiesCanvas").getContext("2d"); // line 34
```

the error occurs on line 34 where it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You have a `typo` on the middle canvas: `</canvas`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have not closed the canvas mark correctly for `playerCanvas`:

```
<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="550" height=600"></canvas>
<canvas id="playerCanvas" width="550" height=600"></canvas>
<canvas id="enemiesCanvas" width="550" height=600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems your javascript is running before the HTML has finished loading.
If you can use jQuery put the js inside of this;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // js goes in here.
});
```

Comment: i didn't have the typo as above and was getting this error. your answer resolved it for me. thanks.